# CSS: How to apply style to a specific class

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I have a css question please.

I have the following `html` code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of dummyJobModels" class="item-search-dummy">
</ion-item>
```

This generates the code below:

[image]

I would like to hide the `border-bottom`. I need to set for the `list-md` class, but for only the elements under the `item-search-dummy` class. I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
.item-search-dummy.list-md {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If anyone can advise how I can selectively set a class attribute, I would appreciate it.

Comment: you want to hide `border-bottom` for `item-inner` ? or there's more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try,

```
.list-md .item-search-dummy .item-inner{
    border-bottom: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I need to wait 10 min before I can set this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to select a class with an specific parent use:

```
.parentclass > .childclass {
  // css rules... maybe use !important; to force an override
}
```

in this case you have to set border-bottom to "none" or "unset"

Answer (score 2):

Use the following selector:

```
.parentclass > .childclass
```