# Changing the FONT color of the ModelState.AddModelError message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider this bit of .NET Core goodness. If you have an error with the state of the model you can just:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
"Invalid login attempt.");
```

The only issue is the formatting of the message is not so nice and the red color doesn't work for my UI.

Is there a way to simply change the message color?

I have tried

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
"<style='color:black'><strong>Invalid login attempt.<strong></style>");
```

but that did not have the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-validation-tag-helpers).

If you use the `Html.ValidationMessageFor` tag helper in your view, you will get HTML like the following example (from the above link):

```html
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Email"
            data-valmsg-replace="true">
   The Email Address field is required.
</span>
```

Then all you need to do is add styles for the class "field-validation-error" in your CSS file.

Comment: I updated my question to contain my form, exactly how would you implement this solution?

Comment: @MisterPositive you have "@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})". Just add a style for the class text-danger in your CSS.

Comment: @MisterPositive yes but with the class selector (".") before (.text-danger) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273893/css-how-to-apply-style-to-a-specific-class